# Combine auto, fixed, and percentage width in same HTML table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, fluid-layout

I would like to create a table that has 4 columns. 2 of the columns in the table are labels and should auto-size to the widest element. One of the other columns is fixed width and the last should fill the remaining space. My first attempt to create this table looks like this:

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <td class="lbl">lbl:</td> <td class="fluidContent">Expandable Content 1</td>
  <td class="lbl">longer label:</td> <td class="fixedContent">Me Fixed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="lbl">longer label:</td> <td class="fluidContent">Expandable Content 2</td>
  <td class="lbl">lbl:</td> <td class="fixedContent">Me Fixed</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.lbl {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  width: auto;
}

.fluidContent {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.fixedContent {
  width: 120px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vf5p0m82/

Unfortunately this markup yields label columns with fluid width. The "lbl" class cells are treated as though they had a width of 27% specified with the "fluidContent" cells having a width of 46%. What I want is for the "lbl" cells to be as small as possible while still fitting the largest string they contain.

Is there any way to do this how I want simply with tables or is it time to employ the new CSS3 flex-boxes?

**Edit: A Solution**

Whilst adding another example to this question for clarity I stumbled upon a hack to make it work. If you just give the auto-sized columns a width of 1px everything works out. See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vf5p0m82/2/

Is there an established/canonical way to do this or is this it?

Comment: What do you mean by `abels and should auto-size to the widest element`? Do you want the labels to be the width of their content, width of the largest column, or something else?

Comment: If you're happy with the [browser support for flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), then wrap both arms around it and never let go (I'm a recent convert)

Comment: @dlsso - I mean that the width of the "label" columns should be automatic. They just contain text and are not wrapped, so the cell in the column with the longest string sets the width of the whole column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more official way to do this, but the thing I've found works is to just set the cell width to 1px. The content size overrides it, so it will just collapse to content size.

```
.lbl {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 1px;
}
```

By the way, the calc seems to be overridden by table formatting, but it doesn't seem like you need it from what you described.

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/vf5p0m82/1/

Comment: Yup, you and I were writing this at the same time, just added it as an edit to my own Q.

Comment: Actually I found that doing it that way wont work if the table has some colspan cells. See new fiddle in my question above.

Comment: It's the inline `width` style that's the problem, not the colspan. Just remove it, it's not doing anything for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a flexbox solution: https://jsfiddle.net/vf5p0m82/4/

HTML

```
<div class="fTbl">
  <div class="fluidWrapper">
    <div class="shrinkCol">
      <div class="lbl">lbl:</div>
      <div class="lbl">long lbl:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stretchCol">
      <div class="fluidCell">Expand Content</div>
      <div class="fluidCell">Expand Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixedWrapper">
    <div class="shrinkCol">
      <div class="lbl">longer label:</div>
      <div class="lbl">lbl:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="shrinkCol">
      <div class="fixCell" style="width:100px;">Fixed</div>
      <div class="fixCell" style="width:100px;">Fixed</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fTbl {
  border: solid magenta 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.fixedWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.fluidWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.shrinkCol {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.stretchCol {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.fluidCell {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  min-width: 140px;  
}

.fixCell {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.lbl {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Ok, so here is how you use this CSS generally:

- Tables must be divided into separate columns and each column filled independently row by row.
- Rows of separate columns must be explicitly given equal heights if they contain items of different heights.
- Label/content column pairs are placed in the fixed/fluidWrapper classes so that the labels and content (usually text boxes) wrap together and don't get separated.
- It is not possible to have a "colspan" within 1 flex table without decoupling the rows from one another and explicitly setting widths.

I like this approach because it is easy to have the flex items stretch and compress vertically and horizontally to fill a page and wrapping items to respond to narrow screens is fairly simple. It also doesn't require hacky CSS like the table does. I find that HTML tables can be quite cumbersome and unintuitive at times.

I dislike this approach because it is impossible (or perhaps just difficult) to make a row of the table span multiple columns. If there is a wider item it must be placed in a new container and will therefore not share its label width with the items above it. However, it seems that these complaints arise from inherent differences in the table and flex box design objectives and that you must simply choose which approach best suits a given layout.

Answer (score 0):

A search for generating automatic table column widths approximately equal to those of the widest column in any row comes here to this question. If that is what you want to do, try `th,td {width: max-content;}` in your CSS. Works for me.